# Rails asset pipeline tests pass production broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, asset-pipeline

I had the following problem with the asset pipeline.

- I have an HTML email with an image inside.
- I have tests covering the case in which the email is sent successfully.
- All tests pass.
- When going to production, the feature requiring the email to be sent is broken, because the HTML layout is referencing a non existent image.

This obviously applies to all precompiled assets.

It seems to me that suddenly tests are no longer reliable. Is there any way to avoid this situation to happen again?

Comment: Have you configured test env to use precompiled assets?

Comment: do you mean "config.assets.compile = false"? If I do that, I need to precompile assets every time I run tests. Is this a possible solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the perfect solution form my own case. If you set

```
 config.assets.compile = false 
 config.assets.digest = true
```

in test environment, your tests will rely on precompiled assets.

Since it is annoying to precompile assets every time during quick development and testing phases, in my case it's enough to have this configuration on CI only.

You can setup an initializer called ci_config.rb with the following:

```
if ENV['CI'] 
  class YourApp::Application
    config.assets.compile = false
    config.assets.digest = true 
  end
end
```

And configure you CI to run rake assets:precompile on start and rake assets:clean on end.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the default configuration options in application.rb, production.rb and development.rb, and read [Configuring Rails Applications in Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) to learn options.

Important options are, followings:

`config.serve_static_assets`: set this to false (production default), then, rails will not serve static contents.

`config.assets.compile`: whether compile assets using asset pipeline to compile if needed.

If you set above two options to `false` (that's the default for production), then you need to 1) precompile and place static contents at proper places, 2) configure web server (apache or nginx, may be) to serve static contents as needed.

So, for production, you need not only place the files, but also configure web server to serve them OR you can configure `serve_static_assets` to create assets on-the-fly. You may need to adjust test configuration but for test `serve_static_assets` is true unless you change it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was looking for an answer that focused on how to setup a test practice to avoid this the described case to happen again.

Comment: @shigeya, the issue was that test environment and production environment configurations are different regarding the asset pipeline. Imagine you've added a new javascript file to your assets but forgot to include file name to config.assets.precompile array. In this case, tests would pass (with config.assets.compile=true), but production would fail (having config.assets.compile=false). So the question was not about how to use the asset pipeline, but how to to make production and test environments work alike. 
The answer of Fabrizio is a possible workaround for this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I think your guess is right for Fabrizio's case. For my situation, I have configured the config.assets.precompile array. so might be different reason. I can't reproduce that anymore, so I can't verify.