# How to check rails compilation before deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I encounter sometimes a broken code that if I run rails c/s locally it doesn't break. Only after deployment (RAILS_ENV = production) it will break on rails server loading...

Before deployment I do RAILS_ENV=production rails s to see if it breaks or not.

Is there a way to test this differently?

Thanks

Comment: The best way is are log checking for the `production` environment.

Comment: Do you mean the same code is breaking in one environment, but working in another, or is it reproducible in dev, but not noticed?

Comment: @Tim - I mean that in development the code breaks only when calling the method that is broken, while in production when i run rails c/s it breaks instantly. Question is - how can I run a tool that will check that the code is not broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've got a couple of suggestions - in terms of whether the code is syntactically correct, I'd refer you to this post:

[How to check entire rails project for compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033087/how-to-check-entire-rails-project-for-compilation-errors) - note that the accepted answer defers to other answers.

One biggie, that I dislike is asset pipeline, as the artifacts are intentially different in production than in development. I'd suggest this.

[Rails asset pipeline tests pass production broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992893/rails-asset-pipeline-tests-pass-production-broken)

Apart from that, https://github.com/yorickpeterse/ruby-lint/ is interesting, for analysis, and the errors list it generates might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Log checking in the production is the best way. Check in log which class or method breaks the code you might able to find the bug.